# How can I check whether a class inherits another class?

Tags: c++, c++11, subclass, type-traits

Suppose I'm writing the following templated function:

```
class A { /* ... */ };

// ... etc...

template<typename C>
void foo() {
    bool C_inherits_A = /* magic */;
    if (C_inherits_A) { do_something(); }        
    else { do_something_else(); }
}
```

We remember `dynamic_cast` from the olden days, but that isn't relevant here since there's no pointer, and I'm checking "downward", not "upward". Is there something simple with which to replace `/* magic */` in the snippet above?

PS - There should definitely already be a dupe of this question, but I just could not find one so I wrote it up.

Answer (score 3):

Beginning in C++11, the standard C++ library caters to this exact need - using the  [`std::is_base_of`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_base_of) type trait. To read a bit more about type traits see their [SO tag page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/typetraits/info).

Anyway, you would replace `/* magic */` with:

```
std::is_base_of<A, C>::value
```

which is a Boolean expression that's true if A is a base class of C, i.e. if C inherits A.

Remember that type traits are evaluated at compile-time, so you can use `if (std::is_base_of<A,C>::value)` in `constexpr` functions, or in template parameters and so on.